# How to search firebase database by value containing object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database with the following structure

```
 ref
  |
  |-- rooms
  |    |
  |    .-- LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU
  |          |
  |          seats
  |             |
  |             |-- east: 'frank'
  |             |-- north: 'mike'
  |             |-- south: 'john'
  |             |-- west: 'sam'
```

[image: Firebase structure]

I am trying to delete the node `north:'mike'`.

I know I can do that using

```
var db = firebase.database().ref('rooms/LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU/seats/north');
db.remove();
```

But the problem is `mike` is not necesarily combined with `north`. He could be at `east`, `west`, or `south`. So I have to search for the node that contain `mike` as the value, then delete it.

I couldn't come up with the correct way of searching firebase db to execute the `.remove()` function.

PS: I already have a reference to the object id `LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU` in my code. So I only need to search the `seats` level.

Here is what I tried:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var path = 'rooms/LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU/seats';
db.child(path).orderByChild('seats').equalTo('mike').remove();
```

That did not work. So I tried:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var path = 'rooms/LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU';
db.child(path).orderByChild('seats').equalTo('mike').remove();
```

That also did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `orderByValue` and delete the child or children using the `DataSanpshot`:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var path = 'rooms/LUUZxjzhMQ9xf7d2-lU/seats';
db.child(path).orderByValue().equalTo('mike').once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      db.child(path + '/' + childSnapshot.ref.key).remove();
    });
  });
```

This will remove all the children that have `mike` as value.

Comment: That makes sense. I’ll try it and let you know